# Changing the hostname/domain for Sylius-Shop

Tags: hostname, sylius

I've just installed Sylius to test it for possible production use and integrated Paypal through the payum-gateway.

I'm running Sylius with the included webserver on 127.0.0.1:8080 through a nginx reverse SSL proxy for security reasons and so that it is accessible through a regular URI.

After the PayPal-Payment, I'm forwarded back to the page as it should but instead of the origin-page it sends to 127.0.0.1:8080. 
The "Show Shop"-link from the admin-menu did this as well until I changed the server name in the "channel settings".

I figured I have to set the public hostname somewhere else, too, but I cannot figure out where I have to do so.
Grepping for '127.0.0.1' yields a lot of results. For example vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Resources/skeleton/web/config.php, but that doesn't seem to be the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to the original question so I won't delete it in case someone else wants to answer.

I solved this specific problem by not using nginx as a proxy but as the webserver itself and deacitivating the webserver that is shipped with Sylius.